# measure the time of load tables with data in hive (its possible?)

Tags: hadoop, hive

I created a table in hive from data stored in hdfs with this command:

```
create external table users
(ID INT, NAME STRING, ADRESS STRING, EMAIL STRING)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION '/data/tpch/users';
```

This users table stored in hdfs has 10gb. And the create table just took 1second to create the table and load the data. So this is strange or it is really fast. My doubt is, to check the time of load tables with data in hive can be with that command above with location? Or that command just create a reference to data stored in hdfs?

So what  is the correct way to check the time to load data in hive tables?

Because 1second seems really fast, mysql or another relational database probably need 30 or more minutes for load 10gb of data into a table.

Answer (score 0):

Your create table statement is pointing to *external* storage for the tables, so Hive is not copying the data over.  The [documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-ExternalTables) explains external tables like this:

> **External Tables**
>
> The EXTERNAL keyword lets you create a table and provide a LOCATION so
>   that Hive does not use a default location for this table. This comes
>   in handy if you already have data generated. When dropping an EXTERNAL
>   table, data in the table is NOT deleted from the file system.
>
> An EXTERNAL table points to any HDFS location for its storage, rather
>   than being stored in a folder specified by the configuration property
>   hive.metastore.warehouse.dir.

This is not 100% explicit, but the idea is that Hive is pointing to the table contents rather than managing it directly.

Comment: Thanks! I understood better now how the external table works. So to check the time to load data in a hive table we can´t use external? We should use create table instead? Or we should first create the table without location and after create the table we use the load data into table command?

Comment: @Jann . . . You should time the operation most appropriate to your application.  All three of those are reasonable under he right circumstances.